# check constraint for date column as format wise check its an valid date during the insertion

Tags: sql-server-2012, date-format, check-constraint

I want a check constraint. That checks the date column, whether date is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format or not.

I have no idea. But I simply tried,

```
create table #date( dob date check (dob like 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

insert #date values( '2018-09-24')
```

So date conversion error is remains.

**Update 1**

**Note:**

1. `@@version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012`
2. If `date` column is in `varchar`, then it is also welcome.
3. Some answers are containing the `convert()`. But my scenario was, front end teams are inserting the values as `dd-MM-yyyy`. I told many time that insert correct format as `yyyy-MM-dd` (as per our procedure). But they cant. so I want to restrict their inserting values according to format.

Thanks in advance.

TamilPugal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #date( dob date check  
 (dob like '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'));

 insert into #date values('2018-08-20')
```

Try this to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` is not stored internally as string so you cannot use `CHECK` constraint.

```
create table #date(dob date);
```

`'yyyy-MM-dd'` is only presentation matter.

As for insert you could  use:

```
INSERT INTO tab(col) VALUES ('20180101');  -- 'YYYYMMDD' culture independent
INSERT INTO tab(col) VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, 'string', style));
```

**[CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

Comment: Thx... @lukasz.. I know the `convert()`.  My question is `check constraint`... Is it not possible..?

Answer (score 0):

DATE should be considered a binary sortable type.

***Definitely:*** Store it with a **prepared statement**, using a **Date** object is some programming language.

Insertion of string literals is unfortunately in the non-standard format `YYYYMMDD`:

```
'20181231' for 2018-12-31
```

For display again as ISO standard date, YYYY-MM-DD, use the predefined 23.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, dob, 23) ...
```

Comment: Thx... @joop.. I know the `convert()`. My question is check constraint... Is it not possible..?